# How to use get_interfaces_ip() and get_conf() features in NAPALM in the same code

Tags: python, networking, device, huawei-developers, napalm

My purpose in this code is to detect interfaces with L3 IP under the "Virtual-ethernet" interfaces in a NE40 Huawei device. I was able to do this step.
As I mentioned below, my question is, How can I see the configurations of these interfaces with get_device() or a different method? Or should I use a different library with Napalm?

## First part of code :

```
from napalm import get_network_driver

driver = get_network_driver('huawei_vrp')
device = driver(hostname='X.X.X.X', username='admin', password='admin')
device.open()

get_interfaces_ip = device.get_interfaces_ip()
get_config_device = device.get_config()

for i in get_interfaces_ip:
        if "Virtual-Ether" in i:
            print(i)
```

## print(i) Output:

```
Virtual-Ethernet3/0/1.3083
Virtual-Ethernet3/0/1.3086
Virtual-Ethernet3/0/1.3087
Virtual-Ethernet3/0/1.3090
Virtual-Ethernet3/0/1.3091
```

## Full code: ( Added get_config() feature to code)

```
from napalm import get_network_driver

driver = get_network_driver('huawei_vrp')
device = driver(hostname='X.X.X.X', username='admin', password='admin')
device.open()

get_interfaces_ip = device.get_interfaces_ip()
get_config_device = device.get_config()

for i in get_interfaces_ip:
        if "Virtual-Ether" in i:
            #print(i)
            interface_config = get_config_device[i]
            print(interface_config)
```

## print(interface_config) Error received :

```
[appadmin@ryugbz01 Huawei]$ python3 napalm_vrp_huawei_conf.py
Virtual-Ethernet3/0/1.24
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "napalm_vrp_huawei_conf.py", line 19, in <module>
    interface_config = get_config_device[i]
KeyError: 'Virtual-Ethernet3/0/1.24'
```

In the last part, with the get_config() feature, I cannot see the configurations under Virtual-Ethernet3/0/1.24 interface, for example. What method should I apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following script can give an idea.

```
#To install napalm-ce you just have to run the following command: 'pip install napalm-ce'

import napalm
from tabulate import tabulate
 
def main():
 
    driver_vrp = napalm.get_network_driver("ce")

    device_list = [["vrp-sw1","vrp", "switch"],["vrp-r1", "vrp", "router"]]
 
    network_devices = []
    for device in device_list:
            network_devices.append(
                            driver_vrp(
                            hostname = device[0],
                            username = "admin",
                            password = "admin"
                            )
                              )

    devices_table = [["hostname", "vendor", "model", "uptime", "serial_number"]]
    devices_int_ip_table = [["hostname","interface","is_up","ipv4/mask"]]
     
    for device in network_devices:
        print("Connecting to {} ...".format(device.hostname))
        device.open()

        print("Getting device facts")
        device_facts = device.get_facts()
 
        devices_table.append([device_facts["hostname"]
                              ])

        print("Getting physical interfaces ip")
        device_interfaces_ip = device.get_interfaces_ip()
        for interface in device_interfaces_ip:
            if device_interfaces[interface]['is_up']:
                ip_address = list(device_interfaces_ip[interface]['ipv4'].keys())[0]
                devices_int_ip_table.append([device_facts["hostname"],
                                      interface,
                                      device_interfaces[interface]['is_up'],
                                      "{}/{}".format(ip_address,
                                                     device_interfaces_ip[interface]['ipv4'][ip_address]['prefix_length']),
                ])
        
        print("Getting device config")
        device_config = device.get_config()

        device.close()
        print("Done.")

    print(tabulate(devices_int_ip_table, headers="firstrow"))
    print()
    print(device_config)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```